# QCache has no method insert

Tags: c++, qt

**I'm trying to use the QCache class, but method insert is missing...**

*SqlTableModel.h*

```
class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant getValue(QJSValue searchColumn, QJSValue searchValue, QJSValue returnColumn) const;

private:
    QCache <QString, QString> m_cache;
};
```

*sql.cpp ....*

```
QVariant SqlTableModel::getValue(QJSValue columnName, QJSValue columnKey, QJSValue returnColumnName) const
{
    QString cache_key;
    cache_key = columnName.toString() + "_" + columnKey.toString() + "_" + returnColumnName.toString();

    return m_cache.insert //?????????? auto complet=te give me nothing!
}
```

*after trying to build:*

```
//error: 'this' argument to member function 'insert' has type 'const QCache<QString, QString>', but function is not marked const

//error: no matching function for call to ‘QCache<QString, QString>::insert(const char [10], QString&) const’
//     return m_cache.insert("123123123", cache_key);
```

**Where is my problem???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `getValue` is `const` function, while `insert` of `QCache` is not `const`.

You can make your function non const, or mark `m_cache` with `mutable`, or create different functions for insert and get.